# Android Emulator with HAXM freezes on Mac OS Yosemite

Tags: android, macos, emulation, haxm

Has anyone else faced an issue after updrading Mac OS X to 10.10 ?
Android Emulator without HAXM runs now very very slow and the one with HAXM enabled freezes after couple second of iteration with some app? Also, CPU goes mad until I kill an emulator instance...

Any help or advice would be very appreciated, Im struggling with this whole day already.
Thanks.

Comment: I face this problem when I choose the 64Bit emulator

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Intel hotfix for the Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager. If you have installed HAXM on your system you should install the Hotfix.

Download of the hotfix from the HAXM download page: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

Comment: There was a similar issue when Mac OS 10.9 was released. That actually caused a hard system crash. It was also fixed by a hotfix that was released for HAXM. I would keep up to date with these hotfixes whenever you are using HAXM on a recently released OS.

Answer (score 1):

I've got Yosemite running in a Mac Mini Late 2012 with 16GB RAM and Intel HAXM installed, also latest sdk version and it freezes :-(

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who will struggle the same way as me - just downgrade your Android SDK Tools to 23.0.2
This seems like a bug in 23.0.5 (Macbook Pro, early'11 with Mac OS 10.10)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: well, it worked for me at least. This is very confusing, so as the next step I did installed Genymotion emulator. Its awesome! I would recommend it for everyone. It is much, much faster then SDK emulator with XAML installed

Answer (score 0):

Just don't forget that you have to manually install the *.dmg file on the the pertaining mac.