# Android Emulator doesn't start in MacOS 10.10

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator

I'm trying to start an AVD in Android Studio, but it just open a "Splash Screen" (where is written Android), and after, there's no progress.
I searched about it, and I found some discussions about Intel's HAXM ([Android Emulator with HAXM freezes on Mac OS Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495910/android-emulator-with-haxm-freezes-on-mac-os-yosemite)), I proceeded the installation, but didn't work.

Is there any another config that I should check it out?

That's my AVD settings: 
 API 23 
 Nexus 4 
 1GB (RAM) 
 64MB (VM heap) 
 Graphics: Hardware - GLES 2.0 
 Multi-Core CPU is checked

Intel x86 System Image (to Android 6.0) is installed too

I'm using a MacOS 10.10 (Yosemite) with 4GB (RAM)

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am facing a similar issue on my Mac.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky not yet :(

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Do you have Docker for Mac installed by any chance? I was just facing the exact same issue and stopping Docker fixed the problem...

Comment: We're in 2017 and still the same issue. Thanks for that - would have never guessed it's the Docker's fault.

Comment: I had the same issue with Docker. Never would have figure it out if it wasn't for this answer.

Comment: I spent a long time trying to solve this problem. Thank you for posting this, it may have saved me countless hours...

Comment: maaan, i spent ages finding out what went wrong here.. thanks

Comment: Brilliant! Hope either the Android guys or the Docker guys fix this before 2018

Comment: This is the error message I receive: _Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release._

Answer (score 1):

As I'm not allowed to comment on the above answer, just to add my own experience. Both Docker and minikube - which will admittedly run it's kubernetes containers using  docker - need to be stopped for the emulator to work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17742664)

Comment: It might not be quite as blunt as the previous answer, but the information is similar, and provides another case where software on a mac can stop the android emulator from working. Which is a direct answer to the question.