# How to fix docker so that it stops messing with android studio from connecting to emulator in OSX

Tags: android, macos, docker, android-emulator

Related to this question : [Android Emulator doesn't start in MacOS 10.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38902460/android-emulator-doesnt-start-in-macos-10-10)

Indeed docker installation makes impossible to start an emulator in android studio. Quiting docker makes it possible to start the emulator but not to start the app (the emulator stays on the main screen). With error :

```
Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.
```

Somebody has a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

So. Not sure how I did it but here is what I did:

- Installed all the updates of android studio
- Deleted all the virtual devices
- Installed only the latest device with the latest version of android

Seems to work... for now.